# Getting a M2IzYzlm.exe in task manager

Tags: malware, virus, antimalware, spyware, trojan

Getting a M2IzYzlm.exe in task manager, It pops up after a certain interval of time and switches off my wifi, when I right clicked and tried to locate it, it shows a folder with a weird name inside the Program Files. Scanned the laptop with Rogue Killer, Defender and MBAM,  but still no luck. Have taken process dump.

Comment: It can be as simple as some scheduled task added by some malware. The proper way to deal with unknown malware is backup, send suspicious files to AV company to let their expert look into it. And then prepare to format and reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to a rootkit.  Normal anti-malware scans usually suck at rootkit detection and removal. You should try out some that are specifically designed to look for them.

There are many to pick from but my personal favorite is [ComboFix](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/). Apparently it doesn't work on Windows 8.1 and newer.  Not sure if that means you can't use it.

There is also [this list](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/windows/anti-rootkit/) of other utilities you can try.

Disclaimer: Make sure you follow all instructions before using these. Usually you need to disable things like BitLocker to make sure that it doesn't pick that up as a rootkit and destroy your drive.